# Why does my @belongsTo field always report null in my GraphQL query results?

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

I'm confused about why my GraphQL query results always report `null` for a `@belongsTo` field, and wonder if perhaps there's something I'm not understanding about GraphQL.

My simplified schema looks like

```
type Image @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  sessionID: ID! @index(name: "bySession")
  Session: Session @belongsTo
}

type Session @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  Images: [Image] @hasMany(indexName: "bySession", fields: ["id"])
  cartridge_id: ID
  device_id: ID
}
```

And queries of the form

```
query MySessions {
    listSessions {
        items {
            id
            Images {
                items {
                    id
                    sessionID
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

return, as expected, results of the form

```json
{
    "data": {
        "listSessions": {
            "items": [
                ...
                {
                    "id": "d5a5759c-d4ff-4ff4-9459-668431ddcf28",
                    "Images": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "id": "75ec7a23-3c79-486a-8dcc-2382bde768ff",
                                "sessionID": "d5a5759c-d4ff-4ff4-9459-668431ddcf28"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "9b0b8308-cc6b-475c-84a1-c2bc1963e2a8",
                                "sessionID": "d5a5759c-d4ff-4ff4-9459-668431ddcf28"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "7fc84c48-2bb9-499c-84aa-76ea21ebc697",
                                "sessionID": "d5a5759c-d4ff-4ff4-9459-668431ddcf28"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "a07a64c3-0b74-4cc1-8d8c-45b80a4f070b",
                                "sessionID": "d5a5759c-d4ff-4ff4-9459-668431ddcf28"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                ...
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But queries of the form

```
query MyImages {
  listImages {
    items {
      id
      sessionID
      Session {
          id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

always return `null` as the result for `Session`:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "listImages": {
            "items": [
                ...
                {
                    "id": "75ec7a23-3c79-486a-8dcc-2382bde768ff",
                    "sessionID": "d5a5759c-d4ff-4ff4-9459-668431ddcf28",
                    "Session": null
                },
                {
                    "id": "9b0b8308-cc6b-475c-84a1-c2bc1963e2a8",
                    "sessionID": "d5a5759c-d4ff-4ff4-9459-668431ddcf28",
                    "Session": null
                },
                {
                    "id": "7fc84c48-2bb9-499c-84aa-76ea21ebc697",
                    "sessionID": "d5a5759c-d4ff-4ff4-9459-668431ddcf28",
                    "Session": null
                },
                {
                    "id": "a07a64c3-0b74-4cc1-8d8c-45b80a4f070b",
                    "sessionID": "d5a5759c-d4ff-4ff4-9459-668431ddcf28",
                    "Session": null
                }
                ...
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Why is `Session` always `null`? Shouldn't it report the specified values (here `id`)? Is there something wrong with my schema, or with my understanding of QraphQL?

Answer (score 1):

Session in your Image schema doesn't tell through which field it should connect to.
Updated schema:

```
type Image @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  sessionID: ID! @index(name: "bySession")
  Session: Session @belongsTo(fields: ["sessionID"]) 
}

type Session @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  Images: [Image] @hasMany(indexName: "bySession", fields: ["id"])
  cartridge_id: ID
  device_id: ID
}
```

https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#belongs-to-relationship